# How do I convert a Vec<String> to Vec<&str>?

Tags: string, vector, rust, type-conversion

I can convert `Vec<String>` to `Vec<&str>` this way:

```
let another_items = vec!["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()];
let mut items = Vec::<&str>::new();
for item in &another_items {
    items.push(item);
}
```

Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 99):

There are quite a few ways to do it, some have disadvantages, others simply are more readable to some people.

This dereferences `s` (which is of type `&String`) to a `String` "right hand side reference", which is then dereferenced through the `Deref` trait to a `str` "right hand side reference" and then turned back into a `&str`. This is something that is very commonly seen in the compiler, and I therefor consider it idiomatic.

```
let v2: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(|s| &**s).collect();
```

Here the `deref` function of the `Deref` trait is passed to the `map` function. It's pretty neat but requires `use`ing the trait or giving the full path.

```
let v3: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(std::ops::Deref::deref).collect();
```

This uses coercion syntax.

```
let v4: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(|s| s as &str).collect();
```

This takes a `RangeFull` slice of the `String` (just a slice into the entire `String`) and takes a reference to it. It's ugly in my opinion.

```
let v5: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(|s| &s[..]).collect();
```

This is uses coercions to convert a `&String` into a `&str`. Can also be replaced by a `s: &str` expression in the future.

```
let v6: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(|s| { let s: &str = s; s }).collect();
```

The following (thanks @huon-dbaupp) uses the `AsRef` trait, which solely exists to map from owned types to their respective borrowed type. There's two ways to use it, and again, prettiness of either version is entirely subjective.

```
let v7: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref()).collect();
```

and

```
let v8: Vec<&str> = v.iter().map(AsRef::as_ref).collect();
```

---

My bottom line is use the `v8` solution since it most explicitly expresses what you want.

Comment: Explicitly calling `deref` (especially as a free function) reads quite strangely IMO, I find`v2` or `v5` nicer personally. (One could also use `as_ref`, `v.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref())...` which is the typical method for generic conversions of this form, e.g. many functions in `std` take `P: AsRef<Path>`.)

Comment: thanks, you are totally right. `AsRef` is much more appropriate here. I updated the post

Comment: In the v8 example, you can also call `String::as_str`, which makes it even more clear what the intent is of your code.

Comment: The `s as &str` makes most sense to me, the idomatic way is hard to understand and remember IMO.

Comment: So, there isn't a way without allocating?? `collect` allocates a new vector.

Answer (score 43):

The other answers simply work. I just want to point out that if you are trying to convert the `Vec<String>` into a `Vec<&str>` only to pass it to a function taking `Vec<&str>` as argument, consider revising the function signature as:

```
fn my_func<T: AsRef<str>>(list: &[T]) { ... }
```

instead of:

```
fn my_func(list: &Vec<&str>) { ... }
```

As pointed out by this question: [Function taking both owned and non-owned string collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32724666/1667955). In this way both vectors simply work without the need of conversions.

Answer (score 5):

All of the answers idiomatically use iterators and collecting instead of a loop, but do not explain why this is better.

In your loop, you first create an empty vector and then push into it. Rust makes no guarantees about the strategy it uses for growing factors, but I believe the current strategy is that whenever the capacity is exceeded, the vector capacity is doubled. If the original vector had a length of 20, that would be one allocation, and 5 reallocations.

Iterating from a vector produces an iterator that has a "size hint". In this case, the iterator implements `ExactSizeIterator` so it knows exactly how many elements it will return. `map` retains this and `collect` takes advantage of this by allocating enough space in one go for an `ExactSizeIterator`.

You can also manually do this with:

```rust
let mut items = Vec::<&str>::with_capacity(another_items.len());
for item in &another_items {
    items.push(item);
}
```

Heap allocations and reallocations are probably the most expensive part of this entire thing by far; far more expensive than taking references or writing or pushing to a vector when no new heap allocation is involved. It wouldn't surprise me if pushing a thousand elements onto a vector allocated for that length in one go were faster than pushing 5 elements that required 2 reallocations and one allocation in the process.

Another unsung advantage is that using the methods with `collect` do not store in a mutable variable which one should not use if it's unneeded.

Comment: This doesn't appear to *answer the question*: "How do I convert a `Vec<String>` to `Vec<&str>`?"

Comment: @Shepmaster Correct, it was was already answered in many ways. I'm simply pointing out that all of them neglected to answer why their answers are idiomatic Rust opposed to ops suggestion. Correctly saying that they are better, without explaining why it is better seems like a poor learning exercise in to me.

Answer (score 4):

This one uses `collect`:

```
let strs: Vec<&str> = another_items.iter().map(|s| s as &str).collect();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
another_items.iter().map(|item| item.deref()).collect::<Vec<&str>>()
```

To use `deref()` you must add using `use std::ops::Deref`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
use std::iter::FromIterator;

let v = Vec::from_iter(v.iter().map(String::as_str));
```

Note that [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str) is stable since Rust 1.7.

Comment: `FromIterator` is in the prelude since edition 2021, so no need to import it now. But I don't think you should use `from_iter()` here; `collect()` is better.