# Split a string and return Vec<String>

Tags: rust

I want to split a string and return `Vec<String>` from my function. It has to be `Vec<String>` and not `Vec<&str>` because I can't return `Vec<&str>`, can I? If I can, though, how can I do that?

```
let var1: Vec<&str> = my_string.split("something").collect();
let res = var1.iter().map(|x| x.to_string());
// I want to return Vec<String>
```

I've tried different versions but gotten `error: mismatched types` and other kinds of similar errors. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Can you please try to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces your issue? You can use the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to share it afterward.

Comment: Could you add 'string vector split' to your tags? I wasn't able to find your question, until I asked myself and got flagged for it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You don't need to create an intermediate `Vec<&str>`, just map `to_string()` and use `collect()` after that:

```
let res: Vec<String> = my_string.split("something").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
```

Comment: It's even nicer when in a function, as the function return type means you don't need the `let res: Vec<String> = ` aspect.

Comment: You can even shorten this by replacing `.map(|s| s.to_string())` with `map(str::to_string)`.

Comment: I've seen `map(ToString::to_string)` as a solution as well. I don't know if that's better than `map(str::to_string)`

Answer (score 6):

You can map each `&str` to `String` an collect the result using `Vec::from_iter`:

```
use std::iter::FromIterator;

let res = Vec::from_iter(my_string.split("something").map(String::from));
```

This question is the opposite of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216514/5189607).

Note that `collect` is implemented in terms of `from_iter`.

Comment: I would like to note that using `collect()` to create a collection out of an iterator is more idiomatic than using `from_iter()` directly, but of course this is not a hard rule. Also it looks like that with the introduction of specialization `to_string()` is also the idiomatic way to convert `&str` to `String`, though I personally like `String::from` or `.into()` more.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Thanks for the comments. You are right, [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) docs says that `from_iter` is rarely called explicitly, and points to `collect`. But in some cases, like in a variable definition, the `from_iter` is more readable. When the type of `collect` can be inferred, like in a function return, `collect` is more readable.