# Split String by Regex to get Vec<String>

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to split an `std::string::String` using `regex::Regex` and get a `Vec<String>`. The minimal code looks as follows:

```
let words: Vec<String> = Regex::new(r"\W+")
    .unwrap()
    .split(&file_raw.to_owned())
    .collect()
    .map(|x| x.to_string());
```

On the last line I'm getting an error: `method not found in 'std::vec::Vec<&str>'` with a note:

```rust
the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`std::vec::Vec<&str>: std::iter::Iterator`
which is required by `&mut std::vec::Vec<&str>: std::iter::Iterator`
`[&str]: std::iter::Iterator`
which is required by `&mut [&str]: std::iter::Iterator`
```

This question bears strong resemblance to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547225/split-a-string-and-return-vecstring), but the offered solution is exactly the one I tried and fails. I'd be grateful if someone could explain the type difference between splitting by `String::split` member function and `Regex::split`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `.collect()` returns a `Vec` which is not an iterator.  You could of course obtain an iterator from `Vec` with `.iter()` and then apply `.map()` but I suspect what you really want is to `.map()` before you `.collect()`:

```
let words: Vec<String> = Regex::new(r"\W+")
    .unwrap()
    .split(&file_raw.to_owned())
    .map(|x| x.to_string())
    .collect();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split on spaces but exclude spaces that fall inside a single or double quoted string, here is an example:

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let pattern = Regex::new(r#"[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'"#).unwrap();
    let s = "swap drop rot number(3) \"item list\" xget 'item count'";
    let matches: Vec<String> = pattern
        .find_iter(s)
        .map(|m| m.as_str().to_string())
        .collect();
    println!("Matches: {}\n  - {}", matches.len(), matches.join("\n  - "));
}
```

The output:

```
Matches: 7
  - swap
  - drop
  - rot
  - number(3)
  - "item list"
  - xget
  - 'item count'
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to preserve a string when the quotes are included? Like: `-metadata service_provider='Test Inc.'`. This should give: `["-metadata", "service_provider='Test Inc.'"]`