# Need help understanding error when converting env::args() to vec of &str

Tags: rust

Rust newbie here: I'm trying to take arguments from the commandline and then match against them. Apparently `match` needs to match on `&str`s rather than `String`s, so I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217302/895407) to convert `env::args()`,  like so:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be1e69216c971440315578c4579fcc63

```rust
let args = env::args().map(AsRef::as_ref).collect::<Vec<_>>();

match &args[1..] {
    ["hello"] => println!("Hello, world!"),
    // ...
    _ => eprintln!("unknown command: {:?}", args),
}
```

However, the `as_ref` part is failing to compile:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
   --> src/main.rs:4:32
    |
4   |     let args = env::args().map(AsRef::as_ref).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    |                            --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                            |   |
    |                            |   expected signature of `fn(String) -> _`
    |                            |   found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r _) -> _`
    |                            required by a bound introduced by this call
```

I'm having trouble understanding this error:

1. When it's talking about the expected and found signatures, is it referring to the `map` parameter, or the passed-in function?
2. How do I understand `for<'r> fn(&'r _) -> _`? I've not seen this
   syntax before (especially the `for` part) so I don't know how to
   interpret the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it's talking about the expected and found signatures, is it referring to the map parameter, or the passed-in function?

The two, `Iterator::map` sets the expectation and the function you pass in sets the "found" signature.

> How do I understand for<'r> fn(&'r _) -> _? I've not seen this syntax before (especially the for part) so I don't know how to interpret the problem.

It's [an HRBT bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds).

Here you can just ignore it entirely, it's just telling you that `map` expects a signature of `(String) -> _`, but the callback has a signature of `(&_) -> _`.

> Apparently match needs to match on &strs rather than Strings, so I'm trying to use this answer to convert `env::args()`, like so:

The problem is that it's an answer to a different question: it starts from a `Vec<String>`.

This means it can start by calling `::iter` from which it immediately gets a `Iterator<Item=&String>`, which is basically 99% of the way there, because it's already a borrow.

That's not an option with `args`, because `Args` is not a `Vec`, or even a collection, it's a iterator which *gives you the ownership of the strings*, there's nothing out there keeping them alive.

And thus if you do succeed in mapping from `String` to `&str`, you'll find yourself with the classic "borrowed value doesn't live long enough", because `map` will be returning a reference to something which is dropped at the end of the function.

Therefore if you really insist on working on slices of string slices, you need two steps: collect the `Args` to a `Vec<String>` to ensure they live, then map that to a `Vec<&str>`.

It would be much simpler to use one of the existing CLI-parsing libraries out there than do it by hand. And if you absolutely insist on doing it by hand, the normal way is to perform delegation and lazy collection (à la `getopt`), not to work with slices.

Comment: "which it immediately gets a Iterator<Item=&String>," aha - this is something I got confused on. For some reason I thought Vec iter() also gave an Iterator<Item=String> but I think I was misreading the docs

Comment: "It would be much simpler to use one of the existing CLI-parsing libraries" Yep, totally agree in general - for this case it was a programming challenge with limited libraries available, and slices seem to fit the (also limited) requirements nicely

Comment: @nyctef `Vec::into_iter` will consume the collection, take ownership, and thus yield `Iterator<Item=T>`, but since `Vec::iter` only borrows the collection it necessarily borrows the items as well.

Answer (score 1):

The "expected" signature is the signature of the `map()` parameter as declared, while the "found" signature is the signature of the function you passed. The [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) function is declared as:

```rust
fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>ⓘ
where
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B,
```

`env::args()` returns [`env::Args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/struct.Args.html), which implements `Iterator<Item = String>`. So the expected signature is some function (a type implementing `FnMut`, to be precise, so some closures are also accepted) of signature `fn(String) -> SomeType`.

Your function, on the other hand, is `AsRef::as_ref`, which is defined as:

```rust
pub trait AsRef<T: ?Sized> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T;
}
```

So it takes reference to some type (`self`) and returns reference to some another type (`T`). In your case, you want `self` to be `String` and `T` to be `str`, but the compiler doesn't know that yet: it has to infer that. From its point of view, it has the signature `fn(&_) -> &_` (`_` stands for "inference type", or "figure it out").

Or to be more precise `for<'a> fn(&'a _) -> &'a _`. This is called [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (Higher-Order Traits Bounds. See also [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound)), but is not really relevant here. It's just the compiler got confused because it expected a function that takes `String` and got a function that takes some reference.

The solution, of course, is to use a function that takes `String`. You can use a closure for that. But that reveals another error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07f6dc587c7893da56f42db425b200cf)):

```rust
let args = env::args().map(|v| v.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to function parameter `v`
 --> src/main.rs:4:36
  |
4 |     let args = env::args().map(|v| v.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Because the string is dropped at the end of the closure, but we return a reference to it as `&str`. There are multiple ways to fix that, depending on the use case. For example, if you only want to use the `&str` in the same function, you can collect the result of `env::args()` to a `Vec`:

```rust
let args = Vec::from_iter(env::args());
let args = args.iter().map(|v| v.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b78a4ad879ea1835fdf94db2bc3174a1).

By the way, because `iter()` returns an iterator over `&String`, now you can use `AsRef::as_ref` directly:

```rust
let args = Vec::from_iter(env::args());
let args = args.iter().map(AsRef::as_ref).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b01459c765774ae279fd337d9f4ed80).