# Vec<PathBuf> to &[&Path] without allocations?

Tags: reference, rust, slice

I have function that return `Vec<PathBuf>` and function that accept `&[&Path]`, basically like this:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn f(paths: &[&Path]) {
}

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<PathBuf> = vec![PathBuf::from("/tmp/a.txt"), PathBuf::from("/tmp/b.txt")];

    f(&a[..]);
}
```

Is it possible to convert `Vec<PathBuf>` to `&[&Path]` without memory allocations?

If not, how should I change `f` signature to accept slices with `Path` and `PathBuf`?

Comment: Can't you just change `f` to: `fn f(paths: &[PathBuf])`? It's still accepting a slice, so there is no additional allocation.

Comment: @PeterHall signature of `f` not accidental, I pass also `Vec<&Path>` to it.

Comment: If you want it to be generic over Path, PathBuf, Vec and [] you probably need to take an `T, I where T: Iterator<Item=I>, I: AsRef<Path>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert `Vec<PathBuf>` to `&[&Path]` without memory allocations?

No, as answered by [How do I write a function that takes both owned and non-owned string collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723794/155423); a `PathBuf` and a `Path` have different memory layouts (the answer uses `String` and `str`; the concepts are the same).

> how should I change `f` signature to accept slices with `Path` and `PathBuf`?

Again as suggested in [How do I write a function that takes both owned and non-owned string collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723794/155423), use `AsRef`:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn f<P>(paths: &[P])
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![PathBuf::from("/tmp/a.txt")];
    let b = vec![Path::new("/tmp/b.txt")];

    f(&a);
    f(&b);
}
```

This requires no additional heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

To pass around a slice, you have to also have the original data held somewhere. To have a `&[&Path]`, then this needs to be pointing into something like a `Vec<&Path>`. But you don't have one of those, you have a `Vec<PathBuf>`.

To get this to work with your existing signatures, you can make a temporary `Vec<&Path>` and then take a slice of it.

```
fn f(paths: &[&Path]) {
}

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<PathBuf> = vec![PathBuf::from("/tmp/a.txt"), PathBuf::from("/tmp/b.txt")];
    let paths: Vec<&Path> = a.iter().map(PathBuf::as_path).collect();
    f(&paths[..]);

}
```

Even though this creates a new `Vec`, this is just a couple of pointers on the stack - it doesn't have to actually copy any of the paths.

Comment: Size not matter from my point of view, but allocation on heap may require a lot of time. I thought about changing slice to iterator (almost like your code, but without `collect`), but still can not force compiler to accept my code, because of Sized magic.

Comment: There are no new heap allocations here. Only references to the existing paths.

Comment: `let paths: Vec<&Path>` so you tell that `Vec` allocate place on stack?

Comment: It's allocating on the heap. But it's only allocating pointers, not the actual data. The compiler will likely optimise away the extra jumps too.

Comment: *There are no new heap allocations here* — **there is absolutely heap allocation taking place**. The entire vector is allocated on the heap! I do not believe there will be any optimizations here because vectors are a run time concept, so the compiler cannot optimize through them.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, that's fair. But there is no other way to lay out the memory of an unknown size of data, in order to create the requested slice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to just cast without any allocations, because their layout in memory is different.

`Vec<PathBuf>` stores the data inline, and `[&Path]` stores pointers to the data (it's roughly similar to `Vec<&PathBuf>`).

You need to create a new vector to hold the pointers. If the size is known at compile time, you could use a stack-allocated array for it. Otherwise `map`+`collect` is needed.