# How to pass `Vec<String>` to `&[&str]` in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a function `foo` that takes `x: &[&str]`:

```rust
fn foo(x: &[&str]){}
```

And I want to pass `y: Vec<String>` to `foo`:

```rust
let y: Vec<String> = vec!["Foo".to_string()]
foo(&y)
```

But this raises an error:

```
mismatched types
expected slice, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that directly: you must write `&v.map(|s| &s).collect()`

Comment: Very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723794/1233251